# C# Exception error when changing datagridview font size using another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, one contains the datagridview and the other one contains a trackbar to change the font size of the datagridview like this:
[image]

I created the following code to allow Form2 to access Form1 datagridview:

```
//This is for Form1, the one that contains the datagridview:
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.dataGridFromForm1 = dataGridView1;
    }

//This is for Form2, the one that contains the trackbar:
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public DataGridView dataGridFromForm1 { get; set;}
    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridFromForm1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font =
        new Font(dataGridFromForm1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 
        float.Parse(trackBar1.Value.ToString()));
        label1.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString() + "pt";
    }
}
```

During the build I do not get any errors, however when I try to slide the trackbar I get the following exception:
[image]

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing out here as I thought I had already instantiated the datagridview. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you notice, in your constructor for `Form1` you create a `Form2` object, but then it falls out of scope at the end of the constructor. I imagine that later on, to show the form, you are again doing `Form2 f = new Form2(); f.Show();...` and at that point, the _new_ `f` has no `dataGridFromForm1` property actually set

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what it was. I didn't realize I was wiping out the instance when calling out the Form2. I moved the instantiation and problem fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new `Form2` and then discarding it. In other words, your constructor for Form1 does this:

```
public Form1()
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();   // creates a new Form2
    f.dataGridFromForm1 = dataGridView1; // sets the property
    // f is now out of scope
}
```

Your `f` is a local variable inside the constructor. When you are showing the form later (presumably by calling `Form2 f = new Form2();` again followed by `f.Show()`) *it* has no idea what the `dataGridFromForm1` is (in fact its `null` by default).

You haven't shown enough code (your method to show the slider form is missing), but *that* code should probably set the slider. Perhaps something like:

```
private void btnShowSlider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      using (var f = new Form2()) {
         f.dataGridFromForm1 = this.dataGridView1;
         f.ShowDialog(this);
      }
}
```

Note that in the above, the slider form will be a modal window and you won't be able to click back to it until you've closed it (which is probably a good thing)

Outside of that you could have a class *instance* variable inside `Form1` that keeps track of your `Form2` form showing/hiding/disposing of it as necessary. Another option would be to pass an instance of Form1 into the constructor for Form2, so it has a reference directly. That *could* look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
    private Form1 _form1;
    public Form2(Form1 otherForm) {
          _form1 = otherForm;
    } 
    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.dataGridFromForm1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font =
        new Font(form1.dataGridFromForm1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 
        trackBar1.Value);
        label1.Text = trackBar1.Value + "pt";
    }
}
```

and creating it in Form1 like:

```
 Form2 f = new Form2(this);
 f.Show();
```

making sure to dispose/etc when you are done.

Also note that `TrackBar.Value` is *already* an `int` and so you shouldn't need to convert it to a string and parse it again. Something like this should suffice:

```
new Font(..., trackBar1.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. My apologies for not showing the rest of the code (showing when I call the form). You assumption was correct.

Answer (score -1):

try replace

```
public Form1()
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.dataGridFromForm1 = dataGridView1;
}
```

to

```
public Form1()
{
    this.Load += (s,e) => 
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.dataGridFromForm1 = dataGridView1;
        };
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are not definitions for "Loaded" in form1

Comment: All Form's inheritors have this Event. In WinForms it names like OnLoad, if i not mistake.

Comment: It's `Form.Load` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx. Nb: Although this answer is not correct regardless of the proper event name, please do the research before posting an answer... Your code says `Loaded` while your comment says `OnLoad` followed by what amounts to 'maybe'. There's no value in that.

Comment: man, in wpf this event named like Loaded. How i must know type of his solution?...

Comment: The question is tagged `Winforms`